# How to restore "Archive" folder from Yahoo mail "Trash" folder?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I'm using yahoo mail on Thunderbird 60.7.2 windows (imap). By mistake i sent "Archive" folder to trash using "delete" option. Now i can't restore it to the original location. Deleting that folder from trash is not possible neither.
If i click on the folder's properties,i get this location
imap://xxxxxxxxyahoo.com@imap.mail.yahoo.com/Trash/Archive

So, how can i get it back to the normal location ?
imap://xxxxxxxxyahoo.com@imap.mail.yahoo.com/Archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem finally by following these steps:

1- I created a new folder under my yahoo mail (the folder name doesn't matter)

2- I went to Tools > Account settings > copies and folders, and changed the archive folder to the new folder which i created in step 1, and clicked "ok"

3- I could drag and drop the problematic folder from trash to it's normal location.